# Cross-worksheet cell comparison and update

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to compare the value of one worksheet ("UserProf") column to a value in another worksheet ("DeptClasses") column. If those values are the same, update a separate cell in the first worksheet with a value from another column from the second worksheet. This will also need to loop through the values in the first worksheet looking for a match.

In essence, if the value in A1 in sheet 1 equals the value in sheet 2's cell D1, or D2, or D3, etc., set the value in cell A2 on sheet 1 to the value in sheet 2's matching row next column (i.e. if D1 in sheet 2 matches sheet 1 A1, set A2 to the value currently in sheet 2's E2 cell, etc.).

Each sheet's column has unique values (no duplicates), and is a number but stored as a text value. I tried changing the format of the cells to Number, with no change in the results. The range of columns in each sheet is fixed (hence setting the "To lastXxx" as a fixed integer and not using End(xlUp).Row to set the value.  I've used this approach for other spreadsheets/cross-sheet comparison and it works as I expect.

When troubleshooting, I did add more variables to display in the Locals window in VBA and 'stepped into' the script - that is, see the values that were being evaluated, etc.; from what I can tell the "If" statement never evaluates to "True" even when I can see in the Locals that the cell values being compared do match.

There may be a more efficient way to set up the range, etc., but this was a way that worked for me in the past, so was trying to keep in that format - mostly because I understand it.

```
Sub Profiles()
    Dim lastDepClass As Integer
    Dim lastClass As Integer
    Dim DepClass As Integer
    Dim Class As Integer

    lastDepClass = 137
    lastClass = 106

    For Class = 3 To lastClass
        For DepClass = 2 To lastDepClass
            If Sheets("UserProf").Cells(Class, 1).Value = Sheets("DeptClasses").Cells(DepClass, 5).Value Then
                Sheets("DeptClasses").Cells(DepClass, 6) = Sheets("UserProf").Cells(DepClass, 5).Value
            End If
        Next DepClass
    Next Class   

End Sub
```

Comment: Your worksheet names are swapped inside your If statement. Also, the first `DepClass` should be `Class`. Since you know your last row for each worksheet, you don't need variables unless the last rows are dynamic, just use`137` and `106` in the For statements. Creating worksheet variables e.g. `ws1` and `ws2` would be less confusing.  I would use `x` and `y` instead of `Class` and `DepClass`, it will make your code easier to read. See my simplified version of your code based on your question's description.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Profiles()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet 'Define worksheet variables
    Dim x As Long, y As Long 'Define last row variables

    'Assign your variables
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserProf")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeptClasses")

    For x = 3 To 106 'Just use the last row numbers, unless the lastrow is dynamic
        For y = 2 To 137 'for each x row loop in ws1 loop through all y rows 
                         'in ws2 until a match is found
            If ws1.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 5).Value Then
                ws1.Cells(x, 6).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 5).Value
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GMalc - that is much 'cleaner' to be sure! Oddly, I'm still running into the issue of the value not updating correctly. I added 2 variables for the x and y cell values, just so I could see the output in the Locals window when I stepped into the code...and it's still recognizing the values as matching. I've re-verified the format of the data in the sheets - have tried Text, General, and Numeric - and it (for some reason) still doesn't recognize them as being the same. My next step is to copy the data to a new stand-alone workbook and see if it works; maybe the workbook is funky?

Comment: @M.Lamb I used your code for the column numbers, you need to check your column numbers and ensure you have the right columns for each worksheet.